# How do I get a meta value from WP_Query?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I've got the custom post type `foo` with meta fields called `bar` and `baz`. Now I get the `WP_Query` object using:

```
$args = array( 
       'post_type'      => 'foo', 
       'meta_key'       => 'bar', 
       'meta_value'     => $bar_value,
       'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
$res = new WP_Query($args);
```

Now I want to check if the value `baz` of the selected post is equal to `$baz_value`. How can I do that?

Comment: [See `meta_query` for `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem myself. Since none of the already existing answers solved the problem, I figured I could best post mine here to help people with similar problems.

The solution:

```
if($res->have_posts()) { 
    $id = $mail_res->posts[0]->ID; // blindly assuming there is only 1 post having baz = baz_value
    $true_baz = get_post_meta($id, 'baz')[0];

    if($true_baz== $baz) {
        //success
    } else {
        //error
    }
} else {
    //error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this one:

```
$args = array( 
   'post_type'      => 'foo', 
   'meta_key'       => 'bar', 
   'meta_value'     => $bar_value,
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
$res = new WP_Query($args);

 to 
  $args = array( 
   'post_type'      => 'foo', 
   'meta_key'       => 'bar', 
   'meta_value'     => $bar_value,
   'meta_compare'     => '=',
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
$res = new WP_Query($args);
```

Read this: [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

Answer (score 0):

The query arguments are in several places in the query object. You can `var_dump` the object and see them.

1. `$res->query_vars`
2. `$res->meta_query` (in this case)
3. `$res->query`

Items 1 and 3 will be easiest to work with. Simple PHP object and array syntax will get the information you need.