# Assign meta_query value to php variable

Tags: php, wp-query

I am using this code for a meta_query

```
  $values = shortcode_atts( array('category'  => 'Test',), $atts );
   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'mytype',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key'     => 'br_type',
          'value'   => esc_attr($values['category']),
          'compare' => '='
        ),
    ),
  );
   $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How could I assign the result of `br_type` to a php variable?

Comment: what exactly do you mean of assigning the result of br_type? Your code shows that you have assigned a value to it. Did you mean you would like to result of the query instead? Or you would like to assign the value and save it to the br_type meta key?

Comment: Do you mean: How can I assign *the result of the* br_type meta query to a variable? Your question doesn't make much sense to me either.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm being dumb but your query says that br_type must be equal to `esc_attr($values['category'])` so to put it in a variable you would just:

```
$br_type = esc_attr($values['category']);
```

Or if you want to get it from $query you would look in one of the places mentioned here:

[How do I get a meta value from WP_Query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117397/how-do-i-get-a-meta-value-from-wp-query#answer-117401)

Answer (score 0):

In your $args array you are defining what content you want to show with WP_Query. You are saving your new query to the $query variable.

So now you are able to loop through the posts that fit your defined arguments:

```
<?php

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

If you want to save the value of "br_type" you will need an array, because for every post there is a value for this meta field.

You can create an empty array and a counter variable and loop through your posts. On every loop your are saving the value of your meta field inside the array at an index position.

```
$br_type_values = []; // empty array
$counter = 0; // counter variable for array

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $your_post = get_the_ID();
        $br_type_values[$counter] = get_post_meta( $your_post , 'br_type', true );
        $counter++;
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

This way you have all the values of "br_type" inside a php variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but you could loop through the posts and add the `br_type` meta value to an array:

```php
// your query code here

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $br_type[] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'br_type');
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Then `$br_type` should be an array with all the values of `br_type` from your posts.